# CouchDB Ektorp Select Query

Tags: java, spring, couchdb, ektorp

I am examining example Blog example of CouchDB. I use Ektorp at Spring for CouchDB. I wanted to implement it into my application. I have users at my couch db when I use that:

```
@GenerateView
@Override
public List<User> getAll() {
  ViewQuery q = createQuery("all")
    .descending(true)
    .includeDocs(true);
  return db.queryView(q, User.class);
}
```

However it returns just last record. Any ideas to get all users?

Comment: what does the generated view look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works well problem was about db names that's written at Spring configuration file.